# download a file from private github repository in nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, github, wget

I need to download a single file from a private github repository in nodeJS. Is there any way to do that?

I tried with wget and curl. They worked perfectly for public repositories. But I couldn't find any method to download from private repository.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a github token for that, given that you have access to the repo.

Example with `curl`

```
curl --header 'Authorization: token <GH-TOKEN>' \
     --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
     --remote-name \
     --location https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path
```